# Laravel Sanctum prune expired tokens is not working when run as scheduled job

Tags: laravel, cron, laravel-sanctum

When executing "sanctum:prune-expired --hours=24" manually in the console, everything is working fine and expired tokens are deleted. This has to be run automatically of course, but this is constantly failing for me.

My setup:

in Kernel::schedule:

```
$schedule
    ->command('sanctum:prune-expired --hours=24')
    ->dailyAt('6:25')
    ->appendOutputTo(storage_path() . "/logs/schedule.log")
    ->emailOutputTo('[my email address]');
```

in /etc/cron.daily (which is executed at 6:25):

```
su -s /bin/bash [vhost user] -c "/usr/bin/php8.1 [vhost folder]/artisan schedule:run >> [vhost folder]/storage/logs/laravel-cron"
```

in config/sanctum.php:

```
'expiration' => 1440
```

The scheduled job does run every day at 6:25, but expired tokens are not removed. I'm getting an email for the job with empty body. The schedule.log is empty as well.

The laravel-cron log catching the output of the cron command shows the following entry:

```
INFO  No scheduled commands are ready to run.
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

It seems strange to me, that I have to synchronize the execution times of cron and Laravel job to exactly the same time. I suspect the error is coming from this. Isn't there a way to tell Laravel to just execute the job, no matter what time? Cron is already handling the execution times anyway.

Thanks for any help on this.